# Rotate an object, the same as the camera rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried this but it doesn't rotate the ridged body

```
?? characterRotation = viewCamera.transform.rotation; //gets the rotation of the camera

characterRotation.x = 0; //sets the x and z axis to 0
characterRotation.z = 0;

character.MoveRotation(CharacterRotation); //doesn't rotate :(
```

Comment: if quaternion doesnt tell you anything never manipulate rotations directly. for your purpose try euler angles.

Comment: Never, ever, ever, ever use "quaternions".  It's a very confusing issue about Unity: they are mentioned in the manual but they should *never* be used.  quite simply, just set the `eulerAngles` property - it's dead easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably wanted to do is to operate on Euler angles. (I think like this cause you set `x` and `z` to `0`).

It's extremely easy to set the angles of an object in unity

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
```

Say you want to make it straight, but rotated by 10 degrees on "z".

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,0f,10f);
```

It's that simple.

So what you should do is to operate on `Vector3`:

```
Vector3 camAngles = viewCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles; 

Debug.Log("cam angles .. " + camAngles.x.ToString("f4"));
Debug.Log("cam angles .. " + camAngles.y.ToString("f4"));
Debug.Log("cam angles .. " + camAngles.z.ToString("f4"));

Vector3 newEulerAngles = camAngles;

newEulerAngles.x = 0; 
newEulerAngles.z = 0;

Debug.Log("new angles .. " + newEulerAngles.x.ToString("f4"));
Debug.Log("new angles .. " + newEulerAngles.y.ToString("f4"));
Debug.Log("new angles .. " + newEulerAngles.z.ToString("f4"));

character.transform.eulerAngles = newEulerAngles;
```

This should work now.

Always remember it's just

## .eulerAngles

to set angles in Unity. It's that simple.

Comment: @Joe Blow, thanks for adding content, but I think you made a mistake - character is RigidBody type and rotation needs to applied to rigidbody not to just transform.

Comment: hey Jezz - hmm, I'm pretty sure you're cool.  if you change the transform, you're changing the object.  It's true that in some very advanced cases involving interpolation and stuff you can use the Rigidbody calls "MoveRotation" and ".rotation".  I'm pretty sure the OP should just simply "move the object" ie, just move the transform around.

Comment: I see, so if you are sure, that is okay. I am not sure as I am not working with physx offen. But why then RigidBody has this methods to apply rotation?

Comment: It's a good question and I don't have a good answer, Jer.  Recall, really you should indeed simply ***never move*** a rigidbody: you're supposed to **apply force** or just let them **bounce** off stuff.  Those two calls are used, I'd say, if you actually want to cue **the PhysX engine** that rotations are taking place. Note too that you can't even use them unless you set "kinematic" in tricky ways depending on what you're doing.  I'd say it's incredibly unlikely the OP wants to use those calls.  I really don't have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I noticed:

1) Rigidbody.MoveRotation performs a smooth rotation to the new rotation over a number of frames. If you set Rigidboy.rotation instead, it will instantly become the new rotation. Use the best method for your purpose.

2) You seem to have put character.MoveRotation(CharacterRotation) with a capital C. Is that intentional? Because the way I see it, you need to put character.MoveRotation(characterRotation) with a lower case c in order to rotate to the rotation you assigned.

3) Setting the x and z value isn't going to work, because Unity stores its rotations as Quaternions, which go between -1 and 1 for each of its four components, so simply setting two of them to 0 probably isn't going to give you the result you want. In order to directly manipulate the X, Y and Z rotation values you see in the inspector, you're going to have to set Euler Angles as a Vector3. One way to do this is to use Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z).

In addition to that, if it doesn't matter if the whole object rotates, then it would probably be easier just to rotate the transform. If, however, you wish to change only the rigidbody for a specific reason, then try the suggestions I and others have made. Hopefully you'll reach a solution soon.